Identify movie about criminals taking hostages at school
I watched this movie around the middle of the 90s on a TV, but it may have been played on a video cassette. I assume it is not older than 1980.
I remember that there were criminals (probably with non-American descent; so could be Arabic, Russian or other common enemies) that had taken as a hostage a group of students, maybe around 10years old, and there were adult hostages as well, which could have been teachers, in a classroom.
There was clearly a diabetic person, that had special needs (so must have been hostage as well) and because of that he/she was given a chocolate and ate it very quickly.
Towards the end of the movie there is a scene when the hostages are running out of the school because of an exploding grenade.
As far as I remember, the main characters were the adult hostages as well as the criminals.
It was in English, I guess a USA movie, and it was not animated.

Could be Toy Soldiers or Masterminds

@Paulie_D Patrick stewert isn't arabic...

@DForck42 He uses "probably" I'm just throwing options out there. I have a couple of others Detention (2003) might be another...but the OP says mid-90s...but again, that could be wrong.

Toy Soldiers looks closer to that movie than Masterminds, but still seems not to be the case. I am not confident about the arabic... it may have been russian as well... but I am sure there was somebody that needed carbohydrates(or something) therefore was given chocolate.
For the year, I am again sure it was not later than 1997.
Thanks for the hints so far.

It may be a longshot, since the hostage takers are American (hey, you did say "probably with non-American descent" not "absolutely not of American descent"!!!), but is it perhaps To Save the Children?
From IMDB:

Teacher Jake Downey has relocated to a small town in Wyoming hoping to escape the urban problems of his last assignment. His myth of rural bliss is shattered when a former police officer comes unglued, builds a bomb and takes Jake's class hostage. The heroism of his true story unfolds as the hostage drama takes many surprising turns towards the phenomenal conclusion.

I recall seeing this as a child in the mid 90s, it was based on actual events that occurred in Wyoming referred to as The Cokeville Miracle.  Couldn't find anything about a diabetic hostage, but it does kind of ring a bell (of course your question could have planted that memory!!).
Other things I recall that may help determine if this is the film, is that the bomb was on a cart and would be triggered by a clothespin, and at the end (spoiler) two adults are back in the room after the explosion and see an outline of a figure on the wall and one of them mentions that was where an angel was standing when the bomb went off (or something to that effect).
Update:
Happened to find the film on youtube, turns out (more spoilers) the hostage taker himself is the diabetic (go to about 1:09:40 in the film for the part about needing insulin).  Guess you didn't plant a memory in my head after all (or I just got lucky)!!!

Watching the trailer only was not enough to recognize this movie. However, I need to watch the whole movie before I eliminate it. Unfortunately I remember too little details about the movie so I cannot recognize it easily. But the diabetic person is my key detail, as it was the first time I see what is it like to have such a disease (or at least what they think is like).
+1 for taking into account that "probably with non-American descent"
